# Why will Foursquare hereNow endpoint not return items?

Tags: foursquare

My application uses hereNow api. I checked-in CORRECTLY (i.e. physically present in the location) to a venue and then var_dump the request response from calling the hereNow endpoint, so it returns "count" but "items" is empty as shown below.

string '{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":1}}],"response":{"hereNow":{"count":1,"items":[]}}}' (length=138)

I attempted the same thing using foursquare explorer but obtained similar result. Could you kindly explain why this could be so and what is the idea behind "unreadcount". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a) Make sure that the OAuth token you are using to make the hereNow request is for the same user who checked in. You must be acting on behalf of a user who has checked in to a venue to see who is "here now"

b) It's possible that your check-in is being recognized as a cheat because you have checked in too frequently recently, or the lat/long coordinates provided by your device were not accurate enough.

Comment: Thank you for your time & reply. Actually, I have managed to use "hereNow" with and without acting on behalf of any user and it works but not consistently. When I make check-ins, sometimes, hereNow returns "items" instantly, sometimes after a while and sometimes not at all. In all of these cases, the "count" data is updated correctly. So do you think your first suggestion (I made sure suggestion 'b' is not a problem) could still be the problem even after what I just mentioned now...?

Comment: In order to see the actual people who are hereNow at a venue, you must be currently checked into the venue. This is for user privacy reasons. As such, you must be using the user's OAuth token to see the people hereNow at a venue. You do not need a user's OAuth token to see the "count" as the number of people checked in at a venue is public information.